# Subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory

i have a problem with an exercise of a admssion test.

Do exist some $\mathbb{Q}$-subgroups that are finitely generated but are not cyclic subgroups? What about $\mathbb{R}$? And for $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$?

Can somebody help me?

Thanks

I thought this for $\mathbb{Q}$:

Let it be $$H= \langle \frac p q, \frac h k \rangle$$

Let it be $n= gcd(q,k)$ so i have $n=aq=kb$. So:

$\frac p q= ap \frac 1 n$ and $\frac h k=bh \frac 1 n$so i have that $ H \le \langle \frac 1 n \rangle$ so $H$ is a subgroup of a cyclic group so $H$ is cyclic. For induction i can dimostrate for $n$ generators.

I though this for $\mathbb{R}$:

Let it be:

$$K= \langle e, \pi \rangle $$. Is  it cyclic? I don't think so because these numbers don't have anything in common.

I don't have any idea for the last one set. I think that i have to consider the projection $\pi: \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$ as $\pi(q)=[q]$. But i don't know how.

Comment: it'd be more helpful if you told us any attempts you've made, any thoughts on the problem, etc.

Comment: finite subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}$ are finitely generated free abelian groups of rank one (i. e. cyclic). You can use Bezout to show that. It is similar for $\mathbb{R}$ except the rank is not limited by one.

Comment: can you see now?

Comment: For $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$, you almost have it: for a finitely generated subgroup there, just lift your generators back to $\Bbb Q$ via $\pi$, and consult the subgroup they generate.

Comment: @Lubin so in general i have that if $H$ is a finitely generated group and cyclic $\pi (H)$ is a finitely generated group and cyclic?

Comment: What I meant was that the lifts in $\Bbb Q$ of the generators of your subgroup of $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ generate a cyclic subgroup of $\Bbb Q$, as  you already know, and the image of a cyclic group is cyclic. Done.